# Is there a overview of my existing shelves available in Visual Studio 2008 when shelving?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, shelve

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and discovered the shelve/unshelve function for me and became a great fan of it.

But there is one thing that annoys me. The shelve dialog lags a overview of my existing shelves. So each time I want to shelve I first open the unshelve dialog which lists all my existing shelves. After closing the dialog I open the shelve dialog to create a new one or to overwrite an existing one.

So I'm wondering if there is way to get a list of my own shelves stored on the TFS without having to open the unshelve dialog before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Team Foundation [Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) from Attrice Corporation.  It is free and has many very useful tools.  Here is what the shelvesets view looks like: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Very easy one:

Just click on "Unshelve" and you get a list of your own shelves (or of any other users shelves if you want).

Answer (score 1):

`tf shelvesets` ?

Comment: The problem is that I'm logged on as a local user that is unknown to the TFS. As far as I see there is no way to pass a login and credentials to the tf command so the command line seems to be no option for me.

Comment: But how are you going to create/overwrite shelvesets if you are not the TFS user?

Comment: Shelvesets are stored on the Team Foundation Server and can be retrieved into a workspace by any user who has sufficient permissions using the Unshelve Command. 
Examples

The following example lists the shelvesets owned by "BuddyTest."

c:\projects>tf shelvesets /owner:BuddyTest

The following example displays information about the shelvesets on the Team Foundation Server to which the current directory maps.

c:\projects>tf shelvesets /owner:*

Comment: All tf commands support the /login parameter for specifying credentials at the command line.